# Bootstrap in Matlab 2013 compute covariance matrix and mean

Tags: matlab, covariance, statistics-bootstrap

Below is the code and the error message. I am trying to compute bootstraped covariance matrix and mean. Any idea why I am getting not consistent dimensions?

Regards,

```
RawReturn = csvread('Raw return data.csv');
bootstat = bootstrp(1000, @(x)[mean(x), cov(x)], RawReturn);
-------------------------------------------------------------

Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are
not consistent.

Error in @(x)[mean(x),cov(x)]


Error in bootstrp (line 167)
 bootstat = feval(bootfun,bootargs{:});

Error in Efficient_frontier (line 2)
bootstat = bootstrp(1000, @(x)[mean(x), cov(x)],
RawReturn);

Caused by:
Unable to evaluate BOOTFUN with the supplied
arguments.
```

Comment: mean(x) is a 1xn matrix, cov(x) a nxn. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I do not really know how output of bootstrap is organized. Covariance comes out as row matrix. They might as well append an extra columns for the values of mean vector. So each output row of bootstrap wouldhave nxn+n columns. My view is not really important here, there are multiple ways to organize output, I am just curious if it is already done or I have to work with indices of bootstrap manually?